# how to find the equation of a circle tangent to the y-axis given two points A(1;0), B(5;0)?

Tags: circles, tangent-line

So I have a circle that passes by A(1;0) and B(5;0) and is tangent to the y-axis. I need to find the equation of the circle.

Comment: Have you sketched a diagram? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If the equation of the circle is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$

$$(1-a)^2+(0-b)^2=r^2=(5-a)^2+(0-b)^2$$

$$\implies a=3$$

Put $x=0$ in  $$(x-3)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

$$(0-3)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2\iff(y-b)^2=r^2-9$$

For tangency, $r^2-9=0$

Put the values of $a,r^2$ in $$(1-a)^2+(0-b)^2=r^2$$ to find $b$

Comment: why do you put x=0 ? :)

Comment: @jdoe123, What's the equation of $Y$ axis?

Comment: it's not given..

Answer (score 0):

The center of circle in on the line $x=3$, this is bisector of line on x axis between points (1, 0) and (5, 0). The circle is tangent to y axis so the radius is $r = 3 ⇒  x_c=3$. The center have distance $y_c$ from x axis :

$y_c=\sqrt {3^2 - 2^2}= \sqrt 5$

Where $x_c$ and $y_c$ are the coordinates of center; so we have:

$(x-3)^2 + (y-\sqrt 5)^2=3^2 =9$

Comment: how do you find x=3 ? :)

Comment: also where do you find -2^2 ?

Comment: $x_c= (1 + 5)/2=3$ where 1 and 5 are x ordinates of points (1,0) and (5, 0). Distance between center c and any point on circle is equal to radius which is 3. Sketch the coordinates and points you will get.

Comment: okay i get it now! thank you :). + where did you get 2^2 from (in yc = sqrt(3^2 - 2^2) ?

Answer (score 0):

The centre $O$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$. $O$ lies on vertical line passing through $(3,0)$ the midpoint of $AB$. Let $O(3,Y)$. Let $C$ be the point of contact of tangent. $OC\bot $ y axis so $OC=r=3$. $$AO=3\\
\sqrt{(3-1)^2+(Y-0)^2}=3\\
Y=\pm \sqrt5$$ The coordinates of $O$ are $(3,\pm \sqrt5)$  So the equation of the circle is given by $(x-3)^2+(y\mp \sqrt5)^2=9$

**Note:** there are two such circles.

Comment: thank you so much this is great! :)